# Filter value on related entity (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have table Properties , that have related collection Adresses

Here is model

```
 [Table("PM101Properties")]
    public class Property: FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
    {        
        [Required]
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }
        public virtual int? LandlordId { get; set; }
        public virtual int? AgentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int PropertyTitleId { get; set; }
        public virtual int BuildingTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual int PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("LandlordId")]
        public virtual Landlord Landlord { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AgentId")]
        public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyTitleId")]
        public virtual PropertyTitle PropertyTitle { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BuildingTypeId")]
        public virtual BuildingType BuildingType { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyTypeId")]
        public virtual PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PropertyAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PM101Site> Sites { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PropertyAsset> PropertyAssets { get; set; }
    }
```

I try to make filter method for addresses (I haму property like PostCode, Town, etc. in Adresses entity ) and some more fields

Here is my method for this

```
 public async Task<PagedResultDto<PropertyDto>> GetProperties(GetPropertyInput input)
    {
        var query = _propertyRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(x => x.Addresses)
            .Include(x => x.BuildingType)
            .Include(x=> x.PropertyType)
            .Include(x=> x.PropertyTitle)
            .Include(x=> x.Agent)
            .Include(x=> x.Landlord)
            .Include(x=> x.Sites)
            .WhereIf(!input.Filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                p => p.PropertyTitle.Name.Contains(input.Filter.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     p.PropertyType.Name.Contains(input.Filter.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     p.Landlord.Name.Contains(input.Filter.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)||
                     p.Agent.Name.Contains(input.Filter.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)||
            );
        var propertyCount = await query.CountAsync();
        var properties = await query.OrderBy(input.Sorting).PageBy(input).ToListAsync();

        return new PagedResultDto<PropertyDto>(
            propertyCount,
            ObjectMapper.Map<List<PropertyDto>>(properties)
        );
    }
```

All working great, but I cannot get Addresses.PostCode for example, like this

```
 p.Addresses.PostCode.Contains(input.Filter.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

How I can filter this property?

Comment: use "ThenInclude" like this: .Include(x => x.Addresses).ThenInclude(addr=> addr.PostCode)

Comment: I think this is not good Idea. Because address have also Line1, Line2, etc properties.

And I need to search in them too@vhr

Comment: if you want to use them you should include them

Comment: Hm. It's many Adresses .Include.ThenInclude

Maybe we have morу elegant approach? @vhr

Comment: PostCode is an entity but also Line1? In that case it sounds like a design problem

Comment: Post code is property of Adress @maxence51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostCode is a property of PropertyAddress you cannot access it directly on the Address collection. You have to iterate throw it.

```
p.Addresses.Any(a => a.PostCode.Contains(input.Filter.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```